# append missing rows as 0 that are missing on other data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop where every time it runs, it gets 4 dates. It must be 4 dates or else the link doesn't work. The problem is that If I append the data frame as is (without any indexing) after a period of time the data starts **shifting** because there was no data with the same name in prior years **"JSON"**. Ex: 2023 has 10 rows but 2016 has 8. Missing rows are unordered and can be any row. If I use indexing, I have to drop_duplicates only If I do that I can set the index and carry on **BUT** then the **necessary duplicate rows** are gone too.

**Long story short, I have to append the same row to the following data frame as 0 if that data frame doesn't have the same named row.**

```
...
for a, b, c, d in list_of_Dates:
    parameters = (
    ("companyCode", each),
    ("exchange", "USD"),
    ("financialGroup", value),
    ("year1", a[0]),
    ("period1", a[1]),
    ("year2", b[0]),
    ("period2", [b1]),
    ("year3", c[0]),
    ("period3", c[1]),
   )

   req = requests.get(url, params=parameters).json["value"]
   data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(req)
   filteredData = data.filter(items=['itemDescEng', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value'4])
   stockData.append(filteredData)

df = pd.concat(stockData, axis=1) #Data shifts becuase following data frames not have same amount of row
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I still dont understand what you mean by "the data shifts"? What are your indices? Could you provide a short excerpt from your dataframe?

Comment: Imagine having 10 rows on df1 and having 8 on the df2. Df1 1st row matches with df2 1st row, 2nd with 2nd but the 3rd and 7th doesn't. But these are random so no way to know on which rows it happens every time. By shift I mean df1's 3rd row is correct but df2 don't have the same named row as df1's 3rd row because it didn't existed back then. So df2 3rd row is something else lets say it has the same name with df1's 4th row. When you print out its like df1 3rd row and df2 4th row with another name is aligned but there should be a df2 3rd row with the same name but with 0 as values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# ... Your existing code ...

# Initialize an empty list to store DataFrames
stockData = []

# ... Your loop ...

for a, b, c, d in list_of_Dates:
    parameters = (
        # ... Your parameters ...
    )

    req = requests.get(url, params=parameters).json()["value"]
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(req)
    filteredData = data.filter(items=['itemDescEng', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'])
    stockData.append(filteredData)

# Concatenate all DataFrames in stockData along the columns
df = pd.concat(stockData, axis=1)

# Create a DataFrame with unique "itemDescEng" values as index
unique_items = pd.DataFrame(index=df['itemDescEng'].unique())

# Iterate over stockData, set "itemDescEng" as index, and align with unique_items
aligned_dfs = []
for data_frame in stockData:
    aligned_df = unique_items.join(data_frame.set_index('itemDescEng'), how='left')
    aligned_dfs.append(aligned_df)

# Concatenate aligned DataFrames along columns
df = pd.concat(aligned_dfs, axis=1)

# Fill NaN values with zeros
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Now df has the same set of rows for each "itemDescEng" with missing rows filled as zeros
```

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects... The data frame must have multiple same named rows and unfortunately I need those same named rows. So indexing is a bit pain in the ass.